# Start Ampps, with root permissions, once desktop loads

Tags: apache2, mysql, lightdm, cron

Been hacking my way through getting Ampps to work on Ubuntu. Ampps will be used to use host a local Web app for my families business, and I need Ampps to start when Ubuntu starts, always. I figure I will leave the PC running but a power failure, or some other issue, is bound to occur on the day I am a 100 miles from the office, and no one will be able to use the app. And explaining how to start Ampps on Ubuntu to your average PC user is never going to work out.

I am guessing it is matter of just automatically stating Apache and MySQL at boot, but then again I am not sure if that is enough for the system to handle directing the requests to the correct folder.

**Update**

Been trying to track down a solution, I have tried:

- lightdm using "display-setup-script" and "greeter-setup-script"
- creating a *.conf in /ect/init/
- looked at crontab (little confused as of yet on this one)

And apparently there is few other options. Putting a *.conf script in /ect/init/ resulted in a permission denied error, and as that occurred during boot I am fairly certain that based on how Ampps is setup that is not where it should run. I think Lightdm could be the answer but I can't get any results. The [Ubuntu's wiki for Lightdm](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM) basically says, if you screwup, the desktop won't load. Well the desktop loaded but Ampps did not. Anyone know what that means? I am not even sure if my change to lighdm, ran. I put the following into a file named "50-myconfig.conf" (used the wiki name suggestion) and placed it the /etc/lightdm/ folder

```
[SeatDefaults]
display-setup-script=/usr/local/ampps/Ampps
```

Also tried "greeter-setup-script" but nothing.

Also looked into crontab, now that is one confusing little feature. Apparently you can run a script at startup with @reboot by placing a script in the "/etc/cron.d/" folder. Still sorting out what the syntax for a script should look like.

To make matters more complicated I ran into a strange behavior with Ampps (Ampps is a mess on linux). If I start Ampps with

```
cd /usr/local/ampps/
sudo ./Ampps
```

it is not the same as

```
sudo /usr/local/ampps/Ampps
```

to get Ampps working I have to first run Ait in the Lxde desktop so I can right click the tray icon and configure Ampps to start Apache and MySQL when Ampps starts. The first way does start Apache and MySQL and the second way does not. So now I need a more complicated script. I need to set a path I am guessing (not quite sure how) then run "Ampps" with root permissions. But it has to be after the GUI is loaded but before login (or use lightdm's autologin, maybe).